# PHP not displaying MYSQLI results

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to create a script that i can keep referring to which would display database entries. I believe  my problem is when I'm trying to display the result I have no idea on how to call for mysqli and query. the ERROR I'm getting is  Call to a member function fetch_row() on a non-object in

```
class connectDatabase {


public $category;
public $query; 
public $mysqli;

    public function __construct($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PWD, $DB_NAME)
    {
        $mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PWD, $DB_NAME);
        return $this->mysqli = $mysqli;

    }

    public function queryInformation($category) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM postad WHERE `category` = $this->category ORDER by date desc";
            return $this->query = $query;


    }
    public function displayResult() {
        $mysqli = $this->mysqli ; 
        $query = $this->query;
        $result = $mysqli->query($query);

        while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        echo "$row[1] $row[2] $row[3] $row[4]  </br>" ;

    }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you referencing `$this->category` when you are supposedly passing it as a parameter?

Comment: I meant to put $category

Comment: what is your problem exactly? i don't feel like you addressed the problem you're having.

Answer (score 1):

if you var_dump $result it's probably boolean false because the query is failing. It should be an object if it was successful. You need to have a fail safe in case the return value is boolean.

Check out the return values:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 0):

We can simplify this a bit.

Try this

```
    $mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PWD, $DB_NAME);
    $category = "something";

    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM postad WHERE `category` = '$category' ORDER by date desc");
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        echo "$row[1] $row[2] $row[3] $row[4]  </br>" ;

    }
```

Comment: that's the same thing without the re usability of oop.

Comment: @MarshallHouse: Which isn't a bad thing for a code example to find the error.

Comment: I'm trying to implement OOP. If I wasn't it'd be a lot easier. 
The error I'm gettting is Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_row() on a non-object in 

The error should be in while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) or $result = $mysqli->query($query);

Comment: @AnthonyLiriano Gotya, didn't realize OOP was the goal.  I was just trying to simplify it.